# Get iframe redirect src when the redirect is denied

Tags: javascript, url, iframe

I'm loading a page in a hidden iframe, which redirects instantly, with the purpose of grabbing that redirect url. However, the server denies iframe requests so no content is returned.

```
Refused to display '<new url>' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

I just want to get the new url. Is there a way to do that? The url is obviously sent to me since it appears in the console.

I tried to do an ajax request instead to no avai.

Comment: Do you have access to the data on the iframe page, or is that out of your control?  Also, what kind of data are you trying to pull.  reason being, is that if the data is in xml or rss format, you could you use google's rss feed to pull external data onto your current page.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is being redirected where and why do you need to grab it? Can you please elaborate?